# ¿Cuál de de estos signos tengo mal?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Tengo un error en `'.` pero no se por que no me reconoce el href. este seria mi error. Me gustaría que quedara como el href como el ejemplo que tengo abajo.

```
<td>
    <a href="conacti.php?id=<?php echo '.$registro2['Id']; ?>"><?php echo $estado; ?></a>
</td>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, pon el código como texto y no como una imagen que es difícil de leer. Te recomiendo que mires los consejos que encontrarás en [ask] y completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio (y ganar así una nueva medalla).

Comment: <td><a href="conacti.php?id=<?php echo '.$registro2['Id']; ?>"><?php echo $estado; ?></a></td>

Comment: Dale al enlace de [edit] la pregunta y añádelo en la propia pregunta, y no como comentario.

Comment: Pon todo el código de la imagen como texto. La línea de código que has puesto como texto por sí sola es insuficiente para responder a la pregunta. Deberías al menos poner desde el `echo` para que se vea el problema claramente.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una comilla simple de más después del echo. Debería quedar así.

```
<td><a href="conacti.php?id=<?php echo $registro2['Id']; ?>"><?php echo $estado; ?></a></td>
```

Comment: no amigo ya que si lo quito me saldra un error al correrlo, si checas las consultas a la base de datos de arriba tambien los tienen.

Comment: @JuanLozano "_si checas las consultas a la base de datos de arriba tambien los tienen_". Este es uno de los motivos por los que se pone el código como texto y no como imagen. Nosotros no podemos hacer scroll en la imagen para ver las consultas a la base de datos de arriba y comprobar si tienen esas comillas o no.